# Why is general relativity only formulated in continuum terms?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, continuum-mechanics, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

So, when we are discussing Newtonian mechanics, we treat particles as point particles. In continuum mechanics, which I understand to be a version in which mass is continuously distributed, we have equivalent formulations.

In Special Relativity, we again formulate everything discretely (a particle has its worldline, its four-velocity, etc.). But, we also have the Stress-Energy tensor, and we can use it to formulate some conservation rules (e.g. ${T^{\mu\nu}}_{,\nu}=0$).

However, in General Relativity, the Einstein equation is formulated in terms of a continuum, while the geodesic equation deals with a point particle. Is there a point-particle version of the Einstein equation? Is there a continuum version of the geodesic equation? If so, why not?

Answer (score 2):

On one hand, [Einstein Field equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations) (EFE) describe the evolution of the metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$. If we assume that space-time is continuous (i.e. excluding discretizations and Regge-type formulations), then EFE is necessarily a (continuous) field theory (FT). As long as we consider classical gravity (i.e. GR as opposed to quantum gravity with gravitons), it will stay this way.

On the other hand, the [geodesic equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic) describes the evolution of a single point particle in a curved spacetime background. It is possible to extend this to a continuous fluid mechanical model that describes the evolution of an infinite continuum of fluid particles in a curved spacetime background with possibly various interactions included.

Comment: I don't understand. In Newtonian Mechanics, space (and time) is continuous, but yet particles are discrete beings and we can formulate the theory as it applies to them.

Comment: On one hand, EFE in an appropriate non-relativistic limit becomes Poisson's equation for the Newtonian gravitational potential (with continuous or discrete mass sources). On the other hand, the geodesic equation  in an appropriate non-relativistic limit becomes Newton's second law for a point particle in a Newtonian gravitational potential background.

Comment: Poisson's equation related to continuous mass distribution. The version that related to discrete mass distribution is simply one that defines the potential field as the sum of potential fields $-mG/r$ generated by each discrete point particle. What is the GR equivalent?

Comment: That would be a stress-energy-tensor $T_{\mu\nu}$ build with the help of delta functions that model $N$ point particles.

Comment: @Qmechanic are you able to give any further reading for you claim that you can extend GR for a continuum?